# Solve the recurrent relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help solving the recurrent relation:

a(n) = 5a(n-1) – 6a(n-2) + 3 for n > 2 (n represents what # of a, it isn't another variable)

with initial conditions a(1) = 3/2, a(2) = 3

I started by solving the next few values: a(3) = 9, a(4) = 30, a(5) = 99, a(6) = 318

But I'm having difficulty trying to think of an equation that is equivalent to the original but can only use the value n oppose to a(n).

Comment: Trying to think of a solution is not going to be productive.  Have you learned the method of characteristics?

Answer (score 2):

Let $b_n = a_n - 3/2$. Then the relation becomes $b_n = 5b_{n - 1} - 6b_{n - 2}$, with initial condition $b_1 = 0$ and $b_2 = 3/2$ (therefore $b_0 = -1/4$).

We then have $b_n = 2^n a + 3^n b$ for some $a, b$. Putting $n = 0, 1$, we solve $a = -3/4$ and $b = 1/2$.

Therefore $a_n = -3 \cdot 2^{n - 2} + 3^n/2 + 3/2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a(n) = 5a(n-1) – 6a(n-2) + 3$$ so $$a(n-1) = 5a(n-2) – 6a(n-3) + 3$$ and by subtraction $$a(n)-a(n-1) = 5a(n-1)-11a(n-2)+6a(n-3)$$ or more tidily $$a(n)-6a(n-1)+11a(n-2)-6a(n-3) = 0.$$

The roots of $x^3-6x^2+11x-6=0$ are $1,2,3$ so $a(n)=a1^n+b2^n+c3^n$ where $a,b,c$ can be found from the early values of $\frac32,3,30$ giving an answer of $$a(n)=\frac32\cdot1^n - 3 \cdot 2^n+\frac12\cdot 3^n$$